# how do i download a database in python- very basic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, download

I just started learning python and am very very new. I plan on using the logistic regression classification to predict incidence of diabetes. I need to download this database(https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database/discussion)

How do i do it? I know that i need to write pd.read_csv eventually, but whats the whole process? do i first download it to drive or something? i would be very greatful if someone could give a step by step answer down to the most obvious detail as i am very new to python. thanks very much

Comment: i) Download the 23kB csv file from website to local disk ii) load as pandas DataFrame with: pd.read_csv("path_to_file")

Comment: i did that but when i actually do pima = pd.read_csv('pima-indians-diabetes.csv', header = None, names= col_names) it says no such file or directory

Comment: Give a complete path to file, or copy file to the same directory you are running python on. You can find the present working directory out with os.getcwd()

Comment: what does giving a path to file and directory mean?

Answer (score 0):

I can't download the database you want to use without login in the website, so I can see their limiters, quotechars and those things. You tell you need to use pandas read function, so I can attach you here the Pandas manual to use that functions:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html
Don't forget to add the import line to use it, writing `'import pandas as pd'`!
Finally, about downloading it, yes, you need to download it, and its recommendable to save it in the same path as your project, so it will be easy for you to specify the path, you now, just `'name.csv'`. If you need to save it in another path, keep in mind you will have to tell it when using the read function, like `'dir/to/path/name.csv'`.

**EDIT:** I just saw the message where you talk about "no such file or directory problem". It's what I was talking about un my second pharagraph, keep in mind you need to specify the correct path to the file.

Comment: This does clear it up a little bit. Im not sure what path means. when i press download and open it in excel (its an excel file), should i save it to my drive or something? Im using google colab. if i save it to my drive, is the process done? can i then use pd.read? because for some reason doing that gives me an error. thanks so much again for your reply

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do are two different actions.

First, you should download the data set to your hard drive. This should not be a problem, because the data set is quite small.

Second, you need to decide, how you want to process the data. Pandas is probably a good choice to do so. Try following code:

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = "/path/to/csv/file.csv"
my_dataframe = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

Do not forget downloading and installing the pandas module. This can be done with pip or a tool like conda. Please, also check the pandas documentation on reading csv files, to execute additional settings (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: thanks so much. this is a bit stupid, but is there a specific way to download data to my hard drive? im a little bit computer illiterate but want to learn python all the same

Comment: @raghavkhanna It is great, that you want to learn something new. Especially Python - I am a big fan by myself! :) But to be honest, I think you are lacking some essentials to fully start programming. But don't worry! You will learn anything needed sooner or later. At this point, I would recommend to start a (free) self-paced programming course "for total beginners". Check out YouTube for this! There are many introduction videos on programming and Python. Good luck and have fun. :)